# Pandas Asymmetric Indicator Variable

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like so:

```
>>> xvals = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9.5, 10, 9.8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': xvals})
>>> df
>>> plt.plot(df)
```

I want to create a second column, an indicator column, that spits out 1 if the condition is met and 0 if the condition is not met. When `numbers` is greater than seven, I want indicators to become 1. It should continue to be 1 until `numbers` drops below five, at which point the indicator becomes zero and remains zero until `numbers` is greater than seven again.

The indicator must wait until `numbers` is greater than seven until turning on. Indexes 19-21 show an example: they should be zero because the values of `numbers` before them are not greater than seven. Ideally, such an output would look like this:

```
# index: 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5|   6|  7|   8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21
xvals = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9.5, 10, 9.8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5]
indic = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1  , 1 , 1  , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': xvals, 'indic': indic})
```

In a way, the condition is asymmetrical: the 'entrance' condition is different than the 'exit' condition.

To solve this, I thought about using `diff()` to find the difference in each value, then separated them into two data tables: one for positive differences and one for negative differences; essentially, I wanted to see if `numbers` was ascending or descending. For the positive table, if `numbers` was above seven, I assigned it a 1. For the negative table, if `numbers` was above 4, I assigned it a 1.

Yet the problem is that this method assigns a 1 to all descending numbers that are greater than 4, even if the indicator has not been previously turned on. Can someone suggest a better way to go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop is all you need:

```py
indic = []
value = 0
for x in xvals:
    if x > 7:
        value = 1
    elif x < 5:
        value = 0
    indic.append(value)
```